# Error codes for Get Subscriptions for a User API for Microsoft Store Subscriptions

Tags: uwp, in-app-purchase, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Microsoft Store provides [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-subscriptions-for-a-user) to fetch a user's subscriptions in a server to server call which requires a user identifier called `StoreID` to be sent in the call.

The documentation of the API on the above link does not provide the error codes, especially in case of:

1. Store ID is invalid.
2. Store ID has expired (past 90 days).
3. Azure AD token is invalid/ expired.
4. Other error scenarios.

Is there any separate documentation link for the same with complete details.

Comment: Do you mean this [Manage product entitlements from a service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service)?

Comment: I meant this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-subscriptions-for-a-user. Have updated the link in the question as well.

Comment: Did you read the document which I provided? It includes creating steps and Notes (for the error you mentioned ) for Store ID and token.Is it the document you need?

Comment: @DasiyTianMSFT I have read that document. In fact, I reached the API page through that document. The document specifies the the high level purchase workflow with the mention of the particular API and its link. I am looking into the error scenarios of the particular API.

Comment: There seems no such document completely containing these errors you mentioned, this document [Common REST API Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/common-rest-api-error-codes)which contains some common error code may give you little help.

Comment: Doesn't provide what I am looking for.

Comment: Seems no such document completely containing all errors you mentioned,if you really need the docs, you could give your request [here](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I recently started testing the scenarios and found these response codes for different scenarios mentioned in the question:

**Azure AD token is expired.**

```
{
    "code": "Unauthorized",
    "data": [],
    "details": [],
    "innererror": {
        "code": "AuthenticationTokenInvalid",
        "data": [],
        "details": [],
        "message": "Authentication token supplied is invalid"
    },
    "message": "The client is not authorized to perform the requested operation.",
    "source": "PurchaseFD"
}
```

**Azure AD token in invalid.**

```
{
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "data": [],
    "details": [],
    "innererror": {
        "code": "InternalAadAuthenticationError",
        "data": [],
        "details": [],
        "message": "Internal error during AAD authentication."
    },
    "message": "An internal server error occurred while processing the operation.",
    "source": "PurchaseFD"
}
```

**Store ID is invalid.**

```
{
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "data": [],
    "details": [],
    "innererror": {
        "code": "InternalAadAuthenticationError",
        "data": [
            "B2B key"
        ],
        "details": [],
        "message": "Internal error during AAD authentication."
    },
    "message": "An internal server error occurred while processing the operation.",
    "source": "PurchaseFD"
}
```

For Invalid Scenarios we get 500 Internal Server Error instead of processing errors, so they cannot be relied on much. Not able to test Expired Store ID case because it is valid for 90 days and not expired as yet.